# How to use Async and await inside of a loop

Tags: node.js, firebase, async-await

I am using Firebase and Nodejs in order to calculate some values. There are 40+ JSON objects will be there in the variable 'data'. 'getOHLCofStock' function expects a value and it will return a promise. But what happens here is, that the console.log function gets executed without waiting for the promise to resolve. Therefore, I am getting 'undefined' in the console.
Please help me to make this function wait and console the real value.

```
const path = db.ref(now);

path.on('value', async(snapshot) => {

    for (const property in data) {
     
            await zerodha.getOHLCofStock(property).then(async ohlc => {
            console.log(ohlc);
            //ohlc is 'undefined', but in fact, its not undefined. The 'await'
            is not working here.
            I want 'getOHLCofStock' should wait until the value gets resolved and
            then only the console.log should execute.
   })
 }
})
```

Comment: You generally don't want to mix `.then()` and `await`.   Use one or the other.  If `ohlc` isn't what you want, then that's a problem inside of `zerodha.getOHLCofStock(property)` and how it resolves its promise.  Please show that code if you want further help.

Comment: ` return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(async() => {
                await kc.getOHLC(stock).then(async function(response) {
                    // console.log(response);
                    resolve(response);
                }).catch(async function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject(err);
                })
            }, 10000);
        });
`

Comment: Please add the entire code both for `zerodha.getOHLCofStock(property)` to your question.  Multiline code is not readable in comments.